# Silverlight - Resharper and VS designer can't deal with StaticResource extension

Tags: .net, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, xaml, resharper

Basically, neither Visual Studio designer, nor Resharper seem to deal with the StaticResource markup extension when I use it "normally" - without the brackets.

```
<StaticResource ResourceKey="SomeKey"/>
```

It's not an issue of finding the resource, it chokes on the property name of 'ResourceKey'. So when designer loads, or if I use Resharper's solution analysis, my error windows are always cluttered with endless instances of "Cannot resolve symbol 'ResourceKey'"

I'm using Silverlight 4 with VS2010, but I had this problem with Silverlight 3 and '08 too. Recently reinstalled the whole stack for unrelated reasons, problem remains.

This isn't a showstopper, because everything works fine at runtime and in Blend (and I turn off VS xaml designer anyhow), but it is annoying, and most importantly, puzzling.

Don't know if it's related, but when I mouseover the "StaticResource" it tells me that the class is "ms.internal.metadata.exposedtypes.presentation.staticresourceextension" - but I was pretty sure that it lives in the System.Windows namespace.

Please, overflowers, shed some light on this mystery for me.

Comment: I have vs2010sp1, everything is fine. Tooltip on mouseover is the same, "ms.internal...". Try to install the service pack.

Comment: @vorrtex I do have it installed - reinstalled everything a couple of weeks ago to no avail. Heartening to know that it's not just an issue on my machine though.

Comment: I don't have problem either and also installed VS2010sp1.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? Maybe it's Resharper that's causing the issue.

Comment: I am wondering where this mystic MS.Internal.Metadata.ExposedTypes.Presentation.StaticResourceExtension class resides?

Answer (score 1):

I found this resource after a short google. Maybe this will help point you in the right directions. You may find that it is completely irrelivant in which case sorry for wasting your time.

[Cannot resolve symbol ResourceKey](http://forums.asp.net/t/1515796.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there isn't such class in Silverlight. Citing [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189045%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)'s StaticResource Markup Extension page:

> In the Silverlight XAML processor implementation, there is no backing
>   class representation. StaticResource is exclusively for use in XAML,
>   using the {} syntax that indicates to a XAML processor that the
>   contents should be treated by a markup extension. The equivalent code
>   would involve querying a discrete ResourceDictionary, using the
>   Contains API.